# Select array2 item by index based on array1 random item by index

Tags: java, android, arrays

The title is pretty explanatory, I'm not sure how to make arrays where each item has items within one another, so this is what I figured out for a solution. Is to make two separate arrays so that when a random item is selected from Array1, the code will then automatically pull the item from the second array with the same Index value. This is what I have regarding code, it's not much, I'm not very experienced when it comes to this.

```
higher.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.terms);
            String[] array2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.url);
            String randomStr = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];
            text1.setText(randomStr);
            text2.setText(?????);
        }
    });
```

So ideally I want it to pull the value from the second array matching the Index of the first one and display it in the "text2".

Thank you in advance!

Comment: if any of the below answer helped you the mark it as correct see : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/333378

Answer (score 1):

It is kind of easy. Just save that random value and use that in both arrays.

```
     String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.terms);
     String[] array2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.url);

        Random random = new Random();
        int index = random.nextInt(array.length);
            String randomStr = array[index];
            text1.setText(randomStr);
            text2.setText(array2[index]);
```

Comment: I knew it was probably easy XD im not very experienced with arrays. Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this :

```
higher.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.terms);
        String[] array2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.url);
        String randomStr = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];
        text1.setText(randomStr);

        // HERE i made the changes            

        int pos = Arrays.asList(array2).indexOf(randomStr);

        text2.setText(array2[pos]);
    }
});
```

> Just given an alternative method of **how to find the index of any**
>   **particular element in array**.